# Blender 2.79 material export to gltf looses gloss

Tags: blender, aframe, gltf

I am trying to export a blender file (v2.79) to gltf 2.0 with material. I am using khronos gltf exporter for this purpose. I have also linked the gltf materials as indicated in the document here - https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/blob/master/docs/user.md

Here is a screenshot of how the model looks like in Blender -

[image]

Here is how the .glb file looks like when I open it in a 3d viewer or in a-frame

[image]

I am not sure if this being exported with flat shading which causes it to not be affected by light when viewed outside blender. Could you kindly help figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your main problem is `MetallicFactor` is set to 1.0, try setting this to 0.0 instead.  A doughnut is typically not metallic.

Also, `RoughnessFactor` could come down as well.  If this is a shiny glaze, it could come down to 0.0, or you could try 0.1 or 0.2 to see how it looks.

Also I should point out that the glTF Exporter you're using is [obsolete](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/blob/master/README.md) now.  Its replacement, [glTF-Blender-IO](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) works on both Blender 2.79 and Blender 2.80.  The new project allows you to use Blender's Principled BSDF node directly, rather than a custom glTF node.  But if you're fine using the custom glTF node, it doesn't hurt to stick with the old exporter for now.